# Pair with tmux but use our own vimrc files

Tags: vim, tmux, pair-programming

I'm looking to pair with people over tmux with Vim, but I've run into a snag. I've become so used to my Vim setup that I do not know how to navigate without some of my basic mappings that I've setup. That being said, if I SSH into somebody else's box, I don't really know my way around.

Is there a way to load some of my vimrc config when ssh-ing into someone else's box?

Comment: You are dependent on your configuration: this is a *bad* sign. Here is something I do from time to time: use `$ vim -u NONE --noplugin` for a week. I'been doing this every 6 months or so (well… when I felt like it) in order to keep myself sharp and avoid becoming dependent on my lovely `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: That is a fair point. I haven't had much interaction with anyone else in Vim for a long time, so I haven't had a need to do this. But, in the mean time, I need to be productive...

Comment: Especially when I am new to the app and the team

Answer (score 3):

I suggest CoVim https://github.com/FredKSchott/CoVim
This is not depend on tmux.

Comment: I had heard of this, but I couldn't remember. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it's just your `.vimrc` file, you could `:source` that:

```
:source scp://myhost/.vimrc
```

Thanks to the *netrw* plugin, this transparently accesses the file from your system; of course, you could also explicitly mount your home directory and then use a normal filespec to the mounted files.

In theory, you could even add your remote `~/.vim` directory to `'runtimepath'`, so that all of your customizations and plugins are loaded, but that probably leads to greatly increased startup times (due to the network accesses), potential conflict with the host's plugins, and is therefore not recommended.